# java web service working with PostgreSQL database

Tags: java, postgresql

my code is written in java, and I am really new to java, so i hope my explanations are correct:
i have a java written web service that works with a data base.
the data base types can be PostgreSQL and mysql.
so my webservice works with the JDBC connection for both data bases.
one of my data base tables is table urls,
for postgressql it is created like this:

```
CREATE TABLE urls ( 
id serial NOT NULL primary key, 
url text not null,   
type integer not null);
```

for mysql it is creates like this:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS URLS ( 
id INTEGER primary key NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, 
url varchar (1600) NOT NULL,   
type INTEGER NOT NULL );
```

when I try inserting data to this table I use an entity called urls:
this entity has:

```
    private BigDecimal id;
    private String url;
    private BigInteger type;
```

when I try to insert values to the urls table I assign values to the urls entity, while leaving the id as NULL since it is AUTO_INCREMENT for mysql and serial for postgres.
the query works for my sql, but fails for postgress.
in the postgres server log I can see the following error:

```
null value in column "id" violates not-null constraint
```

cause I sends NULL as the id value.
I found out that in order for the query to work I should use this query:

```
INSERT INTO URLS(ID, TYPE, URL) VALUES(DEFAULT, 1, 'DED'); or this one:
INSERT INTO URLS(TYPE, URL) VALUES(1, 'DED'); or this one:
```

instead of this one, that I use:

```
INSERT INTO URLS(ID, TYPE, URL) VALUES(NULL, 1, 'DED');
```

so my question is,

1. how do I assign the DEFAULT value to a BigDecimal value in java ?
2. is removing the id from my entity is the right way to go ?
3. how can I make sure that any changes I do to my code wont harm the mysql or any other data base that I will use ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you specify the column name in the insert query then postgres does not take the default value. So you should use your second insert query.

```
INSERT INTO URLS(TYPE, URL) VALUES(1, 'DED');
```

This syntax is correct for both postgres and MySQL.

This should resolve your question (1) and (3).  For (2) DO NOT delete the id field from your entity. This id is going to be your link to the database row for a specific object of the entity.

Answer (score 1):

1 - I think it is proper to use Long or long types instead of BigDecimal for id fields.

2 - Yes it generally helps, but it lowers portability. BTW, using an ORM framework like Hibernate may be a good choice.

3 - Integration testing usually helps and you may want to adopt TDD style development.

Comment: 1. if i'll use long instead of BigDecimal, i will still have the same problem, i must send a value set the postgress DEFAULT syntax, how can i achive that when my code is wriiten in java ?
2. as far as i can see, the entity must be equivalent to the data base table structure, other wise it will not compile and deployed to my glassfish, so removing the id from my entity, seems like not an option. unless i misunderstand something.

Comment: Agreed, BigDecimal isn't the correct type to use in this case since you have an integer on the database side.

Comment: @user You may not need to. postgres does accept mysql style insert without id while using serial columns. So insert into table (c1,c2) values (v1,v2) is fundementally equal to insert into table (c1,c2,id) values (v1,v2,DEFAULT); if id is a serial column.

Comment: well, the code i am working on is an old code that has many faults in it, among them is the use of bigdecimal. but that is not my burning problem. as i understand, my path should lead me to not sending the id in my insert query, to do that i have added to the id @Column in my entity as insertable = false attribute. but it seems to me that my postgressql JDBC insist on trying to inset the ID value as NULL. any idea how i remove the ID Column from the insert query ?

Comment: I am all confused. Are using the java persistence api or plain jdbc?

Comment: believe me, my friend i am more confused than you are. since i have 6 years of experience in c++ and now for some reason i need to support a java application. i think i use the persistence api, since my web service has a persistence.xml where i tell it which data base to use, but the values i can assign over there are the values of the JDBC Resources names i have deployed into my glassfish server, so what am i using ?

Comment: Ok, lets say that; if you have an  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.XXX) annotation for id fields and using JPA and you save the entity classes with EntityManager (generally speaking; em.persist(object);) then changing the strategy to GenerationType.XXX to GenerationType.TABLE. This way, JPA will use a table to store id fields. However, AFAIK JPA (at least Hibernate) does not support BigDecimal for ID fields. On the other hand, using plain JDBC just removing the id columns from insert queries will solve your problem again if id fields are generated as serial in postgres

Comment: cguler, thanks a alot for all your help, as it turns out, what was missing from my entity is the floowing lines:     @SequenceGenerator(name="favoriteid_id_geq", sequenceName="favoritesurls_favoriteid_seq", allocationSize=1)
    @GeneratedValue(generator="favoriteid_id_geq")
once i have added those lines, it worked.
thanks for all the support, saved me a lot of brain racking...

Answer (score 1):

When using this statement:

```
INSERT INTO URLS(ID, TYPE, URL) VALUES(NULL, 1, 'DED');
```

you are telling the database that you want to insert a NULL value into the column ID and Postgres will do just that. Unlike MySQL, PostgreSQL will never implicitely replace a value that you supply with something totally different (actually all DBMS except MySQL work that way - unless there is some trigger involved of course).

So the only solution to is to actually use an INSERT that does not supply a value for the ID column. That should work on MySQL as well.

Comment: well, thank you for that information. i figured that up and marked the id @Column in my entity as insertable = false. but it seems to me that my postgressql JDBC insist on trying to inset the ID value as NULL. any idea how i remove the ID Column from the insert query ?

Comment: @user314536: Sorry, I have no experience with annotation based SQL generation....